# Composer Use Github Before Packagist

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I have made a fork of [FOSRestBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle) here [RLovelett/FOSRestBundle it has a branch `dev-411`](https://github.com/RLovelett/FOSRestBundle/tree/dev-411). I want to use my fork and branch of FOSRestBundle in a Symfony2 project.

To attempt this I patched my symfony2 project `composer.json` like so (full [`composer.json`](https://gist.github.com/RLovelett/5254999)):

```
diff --git a/composer.json b/composer.json
index ec36007..19e82b5 100644
--- a/composer.json
+++ b/composer.json
@@ -23,7 +23,7 @@
         "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.4.*",
         "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.3.*",
         "jms/serializer-bundle": "0.12.x-dev",
-        "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "0.11.*"
+        "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "dev-411"
     },
     "scripts": {
         "post-install-cmd": [
@@ -42,12 +42,18 @@
     "config": {
         "bin-dir": "bin"
     },
-    "minimum-stability": "alpha",
+    "minimum-stability": "dev",
     "extra": {
         "symfony-app-dir": "app",
         "symfony-web-dir": "web",
         "branch-alias": {
             "dev-master": "2.2-dev"
         }
-    }
+    },
+    "repositories": [
+        {
+            "type": "vcs",
+            "url": "https://github.com/RLovelett/FOSRestBundle"
+        }
+    ]
 }
```

When I run `composer update` I get the following error message:

```
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- The requested package friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle dev-411 could not be found.

Potential causes:
- A typo in the package name
- The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.

Read <http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

***What is wrong with my configuration?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Composer prefixes `dev-` to branch names to identify them clearly, so if the branch is  `dev-411`, the composer version for it would be `dev-dev-411`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : `"friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "0.11.dev-feature/411"`

More infos here : https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/935

Comment: Tried yours (`0.11.dev-feature/411`) and then after reading the issues I tried a couple more (`dev-feature/411`). I even created a branch of that name. No dice. Same error.